# Accessing vuejs instance in vuex fails

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In my getter i would like to access the vuejs instance through `this` but it fails

```
const getters:{
   chatbodyval: (state, getters) => {

         //here access this eg
       this.$cookie.get(types.LIVE_CHAT_STARTED) //this fails


    }
 }
```

Is it possible to access the vuejs this instance in vuex

Comment: Could you share how it fails? Error, no-op, ...? Also, where is `types` defined?

Comment: And more code please...

Comment: checking on console.log(this) or console.log(vm) shows undefined